# react-router Location "/" did not match any routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I cannot get react-router to work. I'm following all the instructions in the docs.

URL is: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`
Nothing is rendered and in the console there is: `Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes`

My (TypeScript) file is:

```
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import { LangList } from './components/langList'
import { LangItem } from './components/langItem'

class AdminApp extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/wtf">Inbox</Link></li>
                </ul>

                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function render() {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={AdminApp}>
                <IndexRoute component={LangList} />
                <Route path="wtf" component={LangItem} />
            </Route>
        </Router>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
}

$(function () {
    render();
});
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance, regards,
JK.

Comment: What version of react-router are you using? The latest version requires you to use your own browsing history implementation. Substitute browserHistory with hashHistory would me my first approach if you have the latest version and read the Changelog for Version 2.x.x.

Comment: 2.2.1. According to documentation that should work. What would you suggest?

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md, this should work: `// v2.0.0
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
<Router history={browserHistory} />`
_We now include singleton history instances for you to use in the router. They are browserHistory (HTML5 pushState "pretty" URLs). They include any needed history wrappers (such as useQueries) so you don't have to write as much boilerplate as before. Another big change because of this is history is now a normal dependency. You no longer have to install and maintain history separately. Batteries included!_

Comment: Can you paste your dependencies? I wasn't able to recreate your problem  (ran it using babel, webpack and asp.net core). Here's the code: https://gist.github.com/Mohammed-El-Nabulsi/884fca8a0c73570118a78e44b1ed45e7

Comment: Substituting `browserHistory` with `hashHistory` works for me! `react-router: 3.0.0`